# Let's get an icon for Computational Science!

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was looking through the [list of stack exchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites), and I grew jealous of all their nice artwork. SciComp still just uses the default SE theme. It might be premature to think about redesigning the whole website, but we've been around for a while now, and I think that we should at least have our own icon.

My favorite icon out of the existing bunch is the one for Mathematics:
[image]

Simple and elegant, but with a deeper meaning that tells people what their site is all about.

If anyone has any good ideas, please put them in an answer bellow.

Comment: Once we get out of beta, we should definitely discuss as a community what the logo should be. This site currently uses a default theme because it is still in beta.

Comment: @GeoffOxberry Oh. Can it not be changed while still in beta?

Comment: Yes, it cannot be changed while still in beta.

Answer (score 3):

I think we should use a punchcard. It's iconic, it's at least sort of cute and funny, and it pays homage to all of the simulators and numerical analysis people toiling away in the 50s and 60s who laid the groundwork for modern computational science.

It would be even cooler if the punchcard had an actual program on it. I found a card that has a "hello world" punched on it on [this guy's](http://codeincluded.blogspot.com/2012/08/punch-card-reader-faq.html) website:
[image: hello world on a punchcard]

but this probably wouldn't look good shrunk down. Maybe if someone came up with something a little bit more stylized?

Comment: I dunno, I think this puts the emphasis on computing itself, rather than on using computers to do science. I'd personally prefer to see something more modern and colorful that reflects the various ways that computers are used to advance science these days.

Comment: Something like the matlab logo..